# JQuery remove all occurance of a certain tag

Tags: jquery, xhtml

Due to a complex calculation I have ended up with content produced like this.

```html
<table>
    <tr>
       <div><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <div><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <div><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td></div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How do we remove all the `<div>` and `</div>` tags as they are interfering with the table structure?

Comment: What you have is invalid HTML - you can't relay on client side script to fix such corrupt HTML. Instead focus your efforts on fixing the code generating this HTML and make it generate valid HTML.

Comment: What's that content produced by?

Comment: @ShadowWizard is right. The browser is likely going to kick them out of the table, but where it ends up putting them will be up to each browser.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned in the comments, you can't use jQuery/JavaScript to fix this problem reliably.  The reason is that it's invalid HTML and the end result is completely dependant on the browser's recovery methods.

For instance, the markup you have there will be parsed as follows with WebKit (tested in latest Chrome):

```
<div></div><div></div><div></div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td><td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It may be that not all browsers will exhibit this behaviour, some may parse it differently, because there is no *right* way to parse *wrong* markup.  Fix this problem at its source (where the content is generated).

Comment: In HTML5, there is a right way to parse wrong markup, and the requirement is exactly what you see. The movement of the divs to before the table is known as [foster parenting](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/tree-construction.html#foster-parenting)

Comment: @Alohci: indeed, I always forget about that part of HTML 5.  Thanks for the link, and the correct term.  Still, invalid markup is invalid, so it's best to fix it rather than allow foster parenting to occur :-)

Answer (score 2):

try this? I assume, you are trying to remove the divs?

```
$('td').parents('div').remove();
```

or use jquery unwrap

http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/

-- UPDATE-- don't think the remove or unwrap worked for me, in this case, The browser definitely seems to be kicking the div from the table and adding at the end of document tree
. Try fixing your HTML generation logic to remove the div, if not try adding a class to the div and then add a jquery snippet to hide or remove divs with that particular class

Comment: more likely unwrap, remove also removes everything inside

Comment: That removes all the content too. I require the content of the <td>but I do not want the <div tags>

Comment: The browser definitely seems to be kicking the div from the table and adding at the end of document tree. Try fixing your HTML generation logic to remove the div, if not try adding a class to the div and then add a jquery snippet to hide or remove divs with that particular class.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('div').remove();
```

The content remains...

http://jsfiddle.net/FPysK/

Comment: Assuming there are no other divs in the page. :) the divs should have a class or id at least...

Answer (score 0):

This might work:
Assign an id to the table

```
var content=$("#table_id").html();
content=content.replace('<div>','');
content=content.replace('</div>','');
$("#table_id").html(content);
```